# Button doesn't do anything

Tags: java, android

What I'm facing is that whenever I press the convert button to actually convert the miles to kilometers, nothing happens.

I have 3 activities: one activity for the first screen(contains 2 buttons, that takes users to either the length page or weight page), and other two are the length and weight activity.

So the first button, to go to the length activity is working. What doesn't work is that no matter what I do, I cant get the convert button to work. Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
package com.abhinavbhatta.converter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class ConvertLength extends Activity {
    Button clength;
    EditText mi;
    EditText km;
    TextView tv_mi;
    TextView tv_km;
    double milesValue;
    double kmValue;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert_length);

    clength = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clength);

    mi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mi);
    km = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_km);

    tv_mi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mi);
    tv_km = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_km);

    clength.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        milesValue = Double.parseDouble(mi.getText().toString());
        kmValue = milesValue * 1.6;
        String mValue = Double.toString(kmValue);
        km.setText(mValue);     
        }

    });     

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.convert_length, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

What it is supposed to do is, whatever the user inputs in the miles edittext box, it has to take the value, multiply it by 1.6 and display the value in the kilometers edittext box. There are no errors in the code but when I try to test it, by entering a number in the miles edittext field and if i press convert, it gives me an error "unfortunately, converter has stopped". I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check the logcat what is the error.There must be an exception.

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Props for one of the most literal post titles ever

Comment: You have to handle exception because user can enter any value.

Comment: There can be no "real" answer to this question without error message or logcat but when I see a line like `milesValue = Double.parseDouble(mi.getText().toString());` with no error checking I get suspicious

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for the replies. Uhhh I just started android development yesterday, so im not too familiar with logcat. I tried looking at videos of logcat, but when i switch to the logcat window its empty. Also, i've set the input type of the edit text field to be number and numberDecimal. Also, I dont get any exceptions when i enter text or numbers. hmm.. weird.

Comment: @codeMagic Hi, instead of doing calculations, i also tried just to set text of one of the textviews and the button doesnt do anything. i even tried just to switch to another activity with setContextView() and still nothing happened.

Comment: "Doesn't do anything" or crashes?

Comment: If it is crashing then you definitely have error messages in logcat which you need to post. And maybe post xml

Comment: I just found this out. If I have a method inside public void onClick() and specify android:onclick="convert" then the app force closes, but if I don't do that and use the above code, then i don't get an error but nothing happens.

Comment: Here is the logcat? Forgive me I don't really know how to use this tool. http://pastebin.com/GseKNQ0r

Comment: Change your logcat filter in your IDE to "error"

Comment: Hi @AbhinavBhatta, your code is working fine if you give numbers to your input fields.If you give text then it crashes. I have tried it. See whether you are doing something wrong with layout Ids. And as everyone said, please do check your logcat for more information about the crash. :)

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested you should look into the error log. I'm guessing you get a nullpointer exception somewhere.

For a complete answer we'll also need to know your layout file. Do all the views exist that you reference?

I can't find errors in your code. In fact if I replace the onClickListener content with a simple toast message I do get the toast. Try for yourself with the snippet below.

```
        clength.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: I tried copying and pasting this code and ran it on my device, and still the button didn't do anything and i didn't get any message.

Comment: I believe this is the logcat? Forgive me I don't know how to effectively use this tool. http://pastebin.com/GseKNQ0r

Comment: you should check the log with a proper filter set to your applications package in you IDE. Eclipse or Android Studio or whatever you're using. That will mark the error in red (true for most IDE's) and filter out all the messages not related to your app.